# RewriteCond for homepage not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to apply a RewriteRule to a homepage. I'd expect the following rule to find only the homepage...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
```

This is not working. Any ideas as to why?

The only other thing I am doing in the htaccess file is a simple test `RewriteRule` after the above...

```
RewriteRule (.*) /test.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Whats the rest of your mod_rewrite directives look like?

Comment: I only have a RewriteRule in addition to that. I added to the question.

Comment: where is this htaccess located and how do you test that this rule isn't working?

Comment: @anubhava it is in the web root of my project. If I change to `^/test$` and hit the associated URL, it works. In other words, targeting the homepage is the only scenario where it doesn't work.

Comment: This rule is working fine for me. You have some conflict. Enable `RewriteLog` and show its output.

Comment: @anubhava I tried that, but got an `Invalid command 'RewriteLog'` error. It seems that has been removed in more recent versions of Apache. I have a hunch that my problem is related to Apache version, but Google isn't helping much :)

Comment: `RewriteLog` must be in server or vhost config, can't be in htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, and I'm honestly not sure why, you'll notice mod_dir get applied to the URI *before* mod_rewrite. It's supposed to but I've noticed that `^/$` work sometimes, and sometimes even `^$` works in the rewrite rule. What's going on is the [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) get applied to the URI and it gets turned into `/index.php` or whatever. So what you have to do is match against that. So something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?:index\.php)$
RewriteRule (.*) /test.php [L,QSA]
```

Or more simply:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php)$ /test.php [L,QSA]
```

This way, both `/` and `/index.php` get matched.

Comment: Interesting! That seems to fix it. Any idea how to make sure mod_dir happens after? OR is there a variable other than REQUEST_URI that would give me what the user is seeing in their browser?

Comment: @MattFordham Not sure if there's a way (or if that's something that's desired). It may be related to the order modules are loaded (at least in Apache 2.2).